# If statements in bash Linux

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to compare two strings in an if statement. However the comparison doesn't seem to be operating correctly as the program passes the first condition every time.

```
#!/bin/bash
switch=$(ssh 192.168.14.10 egrep somefile /tmp/tmpfile.txt)
if [ "$switch" == "tmp" ]; then
     echo "expected output"
else
     echo "unexpected output"
fi
```

The output goes to "expected output" every time. I've even tried changing the first condition to be "!=" but it arrives to the first statement still.

Comment: Try replacing == with a single =

Comment: Isn't single "=" used for assignment, not comparison?

Comment: @keyboard_solo, no, a single `=` *with no spaces around it* means variable assignment *if* it's in the context of a "simple command" (basically if it's the first "token" on a line).  The single `=` in this case is just a text argument, nothing special, and is passed to the `[` **command.**  (Yes, `[` is a command, not part of shell syntax.  It's also known as the `test` command.)

Comment: Is that script written exactly as you are using it?  If so, your `ssh` address is horribly out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Your comparison is correct and idiomatic Bash code.

Try inserting `echo "switch='$switch'"` before the `if` to see what the variable contents are each time.

Comment: Yes. I've tried that... I'm really not sure what's wrong at this point. The weird thing is that when I change the first statement with the "==" to "!=", I get the first condition either way. The output is "expected output". But when I change the text of the first statement "tmp" to "abctmp" while its "==", then the condition goes to the second statement, yielding "unexpected output"

Answer (score 0):

Change the first line from:

```
switch=$(ssh 192.16810.10.10 egrep somefile /tmp/tmpfile.txt)
```

To the following:

```
export switch=$(ssh 192.16810.10.10 egrep somefile /tmp/tmpfile.txt)
```

I've encountered a near identical problem many times before, or when when incrementing a variable. Where `variable=$variable++` or `variable=$variable+1` would append the text string `"+1"` or `"++"` to the end each time it looped instead of incrementing like it like it should.

Using `let variable=$variable++` or `let variable=$variable+1` immediately fixed the issue. Using `export` also worked if everything was set before the loop started.

I believe bash is doing something wrong when it stores that variable. Thus it makes the comparison act up, and using let/export does something different to store it. I was searching for an answer to the same question, except I was getting inconsistent results comparing numbers instead of strings. In any case, it can't hurt to try using export before the first statement.

Comment: Sorry for editing that post so many times. But, I typed the wrong

Comment: thing to use for text variables. Also sorry for double commenting, as I'm new here and didn't know you couldn't press enter in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I would start by ruling out spurious spaces:

```
if [ "$(printf "%s" "$switch"| tr -d " ")" = tmp ]; then
```

If still unsuccessful, add both of these lines before the test. If their output is different, fix your test.

```
echo tmp | od -c
echo "$switch" | od -c
```

Comment: Good point. I made sure to remove spaces by doing 'pipe' 'sed'. I echoed both items being compared before the if statement so I can manually check. I'm not really sure what the issue is at this point. Thanks for the pointers.